# Get collection with exists() security rule

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a collection called "classrooms" with the following security rule:

```
match /classrooms/{classroom} {
    allow read, write: if request.auth != null && exists(/$(request.path)/users/$(request.auth.uid));
}
```

I only want users to be able to access the documents where they have a document with their user ID in "classrooms/{classroom}/users".

The above rules work for getting an individual document, but I get a permissions error when calling the collection (obviously because it's also trying to get documents I can't access, and security rules aren't filters).

How would I write a query to get the classrooms collection with the JS library and the above security rule without getting the "Missing or Insufficient permissions" error? Thanks

Comment: Are you tring to get documents in collection more then 10 documents? If you using .limit(10) the error still exists?